# Specify managed disk names in Azure when creating vm from image

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We created an image from a VM that had two disks, an OS and Data disk for MySQL.

If I create a vm from the image the disk resources get funky suffixes.  Is it possible to specify the name of the resources for both disks?

Looks like if done through CLI I can use the os-disk-name parameter, but I don't seen any way to specify the name of the additional disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Looks like if done through CLI I can use the os-disk-name parameter,
>   but I don't seen any way to specify the name of the additional disk.

You are right, for now, Azure CLI 2.0 does **not** support specify the name of data disk with command `az vm create`.

As a workaround, we can use this command to create data disk and specify the name of it.

```
az disk create -n MyDisk -g MyResourceGroup --size-gb 10 --location eastus2
```

Then we can use this parameter `--attach-data-disks`  to attach this data disk to new VM, script like this:

```
az vm create -n jasonvm -g jasonvm --image centos  --os-disk-name jasonosdisk --admin-username jason --admin-password password --public-ip-address "" --attch-data-disks mydisk
```

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Yes,  this is basically what I have done now.  But instead of creating a new disk, I deleted my original VM that I created the image from, and attached the data disk to my new VM.   The challenge moving forward is that I want to create many VMs from my image.  The VM contains 2 disk, with data on each.  I really want to specify the name of the second disk, and it would be a pain point to create a new disk and attach because then I would have the extra step of putting the data back on the disk.

Comment: @Jeremy Do you mean you want to attach data disks to new VM, not create a data disk, name it and attach it to new VM? Sorry for my misunderstand, if you just want to attach existing data disks to new VM, we can use this parameter `--attach-data-disks` . "Attach existing data disks to the VM. Can use the name or ID of a managed disk or the URI to an unmanaged disk VHD.", please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vm_create).

Comment: My image is a Ubuntu 16.04 with MySQL configured to use the 2nd data disk for the db files.   When I build a new vm from the image I get a MySQL setup fully configured which is awesome (a vm with 2 disks).  I just want control over the name of that 2nd disk (the Azure resource).